# I want to add space between li tags with SHIFT+ENTER in wysiwyg editor of wordpress i am adding <br/> tag but it is getting removed on save

Tags: php, html, wordpress, list, wysiwyg

I want to add space between li tags with SHIFT+ENTER in wysiwyg editor of wordpress i am adding 
 tag but it is getting removed when i am saving the changes.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `margin-top` and/or `margin-bottom` to the `li` elements in your CSS in order to create a vertical distance between them. Try this rule:

```
li {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

And if that particular list (i.e. its `ul` parent) has a class applied to it in the HTML code, use that class in the CSS selector *before*  the `li`, like this:

```
ul.yourclass li {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi
Please check the attached image of issue of wordpress editor. I want the space between the list items using SHIFT+ENTER in the wysiwyg editor of the wordpress. I am adding the <br/> by the filter code of wordpress for space between the list items but it is getting remove when i am saving the changes & not reflecting on website.

Comment: Yes, you wrote the same in your question, and my answer refers to that. You know what CSS is? If not, this forum (which is about programming problems) isn't really the place to ask.